# divisibility question: if two integers can both divide each other, do they have to be equal?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

if x ,y ∈ Z. and x|y,y|x,then x does NOT equal to y.
Can anyone give me a counter example please?

Comment: Hint: not all integers are positive ;-)

Comment: Put $x=5$ and $y=-5.$ You can prove that if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ then $|a|=|b|,$ that is, they are equal if and only if both are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *general* integers $x, y$, if $x | y$ and $y | x$ then you can't quite conclude $x = y$. But the following holds:
$$
\forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \;:\;
(x \mid y \text{ and } y \mid x) \implies |x| = |y|. \tag{1}
$$

In particular, if $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, then $x | y$ and $y | x$ implies $x = y$.

Answer (score 2):

For positive integers $x$ and $y$
if $x|y$ and $y|x$
then $x=y$.

Proof:

By prime factorization,
let
$x = \prod_p p^{x_p}$
and
$y = \prod_p p^{y_p}$
.

If $x|y$ then
$x_p \le y_p$.
If $y|x$ then
$y_p \le x_p$.

Therefore,
if $x|y$ and $y|x$
then
$x_p \le y_p$
and
$y_p \le x_p$,
so
$x_p = y_p$
so that
$x = y$.

Answer (score 2):

A really trivial proof
for positive $x$ and $y$.

If $x|y$,
then
$y = ax$
where $a \ge 1$.

If $y|x$,
then
$x = by$
where $b \ge 1$.

Therefore
$x = by
=bax
$
so
$ba = 1$.
Since $a\ge 1$ and
$b \ge 1$,
we must have
$a = b = 1$
so $x = y
$.